# The name 'fe' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multiple-forms

please help i have two forms in which i have to call a method from the first form in second form... but i am stuck because of the error stated above. And i need to close the form when my second form closes.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Passengerdetail : Form
{
    passengerDetailClass pd = new passengerDetailClass();

    Flightentry fe = new Flightentry();        //if i remove this code

    public Passengerdetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fe.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(fe_FormClosed);  //this line gives error mentioned above.
    }

    void fe_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Passengerdetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Flightentry fe = new Flightentry(this);        //this code lets me access the method from the other form removing it will mean no method =(

        this.Hide();
        fe.Owner = this;
        fe.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }

    public void insertData()
    {
        pd.Insert();     //i want to access this method
    }

}
```

}

the code for the second form is as follows...

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Flightentry : Form
{

    flightDetail fd = new flightDetail();

    private Passengerdetail pd;


    public Flightentry(Passengerdetail paDet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pd = paDet;
    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pd.insertData();\\i call the insert method from the previous form here.

        fd.Insert(comboBox1.Text,comboBox2.Text,comboBox3.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox8.Text,dateTimePicker1.Text,textBox6.Text,textBox5.Text);
    }

    private void Flightentry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Flightentry_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Owner.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you surprised that commenting out the declaration for a variable creates compile errors down the road? What did you think would happen?

Comment: nope i commented that out so you guys can take a look

Comment: trust me, we know what happens when you get rid of a necessary declaration.

Comment: i want to close passengerdetail when i close Flightentry also i want to pass the insert data method on to flightentry form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is it happening here?

```
//Flightentry fe = new Flightentry();        //if i remove this code

public Passengerdetail()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fe.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(fe_FormClosed);  //this line gives error mentioned above.
}
```

because you've commented out the declaration for `fe`

---

In light of your comments, I think you want something like the following

```
Flightentry fe;

public Passengerdetail()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fe = new Flightentry(this)
    fe.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(fe_FormClosed);  //this line gives error mentioned above.
}

...

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    fe.Owner = this;
    fe.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: yes... its happening here....

Comment: but if i remove this line Flightentry fe = new Flightentry(this); i wont be able to access the method in the other form

Comment: @MoniXx you can put that line in the constructor for PassengerDetail.

Comment: okey? can you show me how??

Comment: @MoniXx: Ctrl-C followed by Ctrl-V.

Comment: @MoniXx i've edited my post.  with 3 potential solutions

Comment: well if i use this in my button "fe = new Flightentry(this);" and un comment out "Flightentry fe = new Flightentry();" then i get flightentry doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments..

Comment: sorry new to this and programming =P